# NodeJS download file yields exception: HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my `NodeJS application`, I am calling a third-party `RESTful` service to download a file. I use the [request module](https://github.com/request/request) for actual doing the call. My code looks like this:

```
function downloadDocument (req, res) {
    var r = request({
        url: 'url/to/document',
        headers: {
            'AUTHTICKET': 'some-auth-ticket'
        }
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        req.log.error('File download failed', err);
    }).pipe(res);
}
```

The variables `res` and `req` are from [Express](http://expressjs.com/). Basically, my node application is just forwarding the original request (coming directly from the browser) and just adds the authentication ticket. This worked fine for me in past applications, but now I'm getting the following exception:

```
[Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 5816, code: 'HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT'
```

It seems to be some problem with a wrong content length returned by the target server, but I couldn't find any fix for this issue. Has anybody encountered this exception before and could give me a pointer in the right direction? Thank you!

## Update

Calling the `third-party API` directly from the browser works. As soon as I switch to calling it from `NodeJS`, it fails again.

Comment: have you examined the responses without the request module? i.e just hitting the RESTful api with node's native http module to check the response?

Comment: @shennan I have tried the native `http` module as well as other libraries. It seems that many of them rely on the native `http` module and just facilitate the calls. I got the same error on all of them.

Comment: The HTTP response from the third-party server is invalid, according to Node (try calling it using a CLI tool like `curl`). So ultimately, the server has to be fixed.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for your input, could you please have a look at my updated question?

Comment: This is going to be hard to solve without the SO community being able to hit the api. My advise would be to read [these](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4863) [issues](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8514) [on](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5479) [Github](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7019) and try to determine where the error is being thrown. Node seems a bit stricter on parsing HTTP responses than browsers because it's server-side.

Comment: @shennan Yes, I thought it will be hard to find a concrete solution for the problem, but thanks for helping me out. Maybe there is a way to relax node's http parsing? Every http module I tried is relying on the native module, so there was no difference.

Comment: You could try catching the error with `http.get( /* whatever */ ).on('error', function(err){ console.log(err.message); });`

Comment: did you solve it? I have the same problem, is not working from my code using https module or using follow-rediretcs. But it works when I call it from the browser or postman